# Rails nested User Profile fields with Devise not retaining input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-attributes

I am trying to add forms fields to my Devise user registration view. This has been achieved and the validation runs when I submit the form. However, if I get any form errors, the input data does not re-populate the form field as per the original form although I can see the correct values in my little debugger I've added to the development views.

Here is my view:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<% resource.build_profile %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :username %> <i>(this cannot be changed so choose wisely)</i><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
        <div><%= profile_form.label :full_name %><br />
        <%= profile_form.text_field :full_name %></div>

        <div><%= profile_form.label :birth_date %><br />
        <%= profile_form.date_select :birth_date, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year - 80, order: [:day, :month, :year], prompt: { day: 'Choose day', month: 'Choose month', year: 'Choose year' } %></div>

        <div><%= profile_form.label :gender %><br />
        <%= profile_form.select :gender, { "Male" => '0', "Female" => '1' } %></div>

        <div><%= profile_form.label :postcode %><br />
        <%= profile_form.text_field :postcode %></div>

        <div><%= profile_form.label :description, "About you" %><br />
        <%= profile_form.text_area :description %></div>
    <% end %>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I don't have a controller code to show because it uses the Devise code inside the Gem. What am I doing wrong / not doing?

Answer (score 1):

You are rebuilding the profile every time with `build_profile`, it means that when the form in going to be redisplayed, it's using a new instance of profile, not the one with errors. Just change that code so it only builds the profile if one does not exist:

```
resource.build_profile unless resource.profile
```

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Carlos' answer helped me solve this exact issue.

```
resource.build_profile unless resource.profile
```

Comment: Found this suggestion after having terrible problems based on some answers thx for sharing this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your user model has a reference to the profile model, try passing

```
<%= f.fields_for resource.profile do |profile_form| %>
```

Right now, you're passing a reference to a model, but the form wants an instance.

Comment: I've tried that and I get a message telling me it can't mass asign :profile. If I add it to the attr_accessible list, I get a `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in RegistrationsController#create

Profile(#70114845017280) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70114830339360)`